# my GET route not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel and working on a form.

This is the form

```
<form action="/product" method="GET">
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter product name" />
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Search" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the `Route` I have written

```
Route::get('/product/{product}', 'FlashCartController@find_product');
```

When I submit my form it says

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

How do I submit this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need product ID in the form action. For example

```
<form action="/product/{{$productId}}" method="GET">
```

If you just want to create new product then lose the {product} and change the GET to POST as forms are submitted with mostly with POST.

```
<form action="/product" method="POST">

Route::post('/product', 'FlashCartController@find_product');
```

Comment: Thank you! i got it now!